# SQL Insert in to TAble B based using data from Table A

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, lets call them Table A and Table B

Table A has n columns and I am interested in two specific columns call them C1 and C2. I need that data in Table 2

Table B has n columns and 2 of the columns are the same data from Table A,  C1 and C2

I need a Script that will take each Row in Table A and create a new record in Table 2 using C1 and C2 from Table A.

The rest of the columns in Table B will have a default value as a DateTime being 12/30/1899 12:00:00 AM. I need the script to also convert that default DateTime to UTC. I have a function that will do that but I need this all in a single script that can be ram

Here is my function for DateTime conversion

```
        -- Declare the return variable here 
DECLARE @utcDateTime datetime 
IF @localDateTime IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN 
    SET @utcDateTime = DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, GETDATE(), GETUTCDATE()), @localDateTime) 
END 
-- Return the result of the function 
RETURN @utcDateTime
```

Can anyone help me out with this query and using the function to convert?

Comment: Your syntax looks a lot like SQL Server, so I added that tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you describe it, this appears to be a basic insert:

```
insert into tableb(c1, c2)
     select c1, c2
     from tablea;
```

If you want to assign other columns to the result of your function, you can do:

```
insert into tableb(c1, c2, c3, . . .)
     select c1, c2,
            DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, GETDATE(), GETUTCDATE()), @localDateTime), . . .
     from tablea;
```

Just repeat the function or expression for each column.  (I'm not sure if this is the best way to do the conversion, but this is how you have written your function.)

Comment: Perfect, Worked like a charm. Thanks again!